# How to get JToolBar to cover the entire height of window?

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I have written the following, producing a toolbar on the right only as high as the two buttons in it.  I would like the toolbar to run the height of the window - top to bottom. What do I have to do?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AmtFrame extends JFrame {

    private JToolBar toolBar = null;
    private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[5];
    private Container cp = null;

    AmtFrame() {
        super("AMT");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000, 600);

        // tool bar
        toolBar = new JToolBar("TaskBar", JToolBar.VERTICAL);
        toolBar.add(buttons[0] = new JButton("Data Entry"));
        toolBar.add(buttons[1] = new JButton("Operations"));

        // layout
        cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AmtFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it does not span top to bottom? Try setting the background color of the toolbar, and you will see that it does span the entire height.

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  I will have to play around with color, and the nice thing the other answer did - set it to horizontal orientation with GridLayout (made the buttons the same size).  But I would also like to space out the buttons along it, with some at top, and some at bottom. Does a JToolBar do things that JPanels would not (for this)?

Answer (score 5):

If you do not need to move the `JToolBar` here is what this piece of code will produce (I know it may not be the exact thing you're looking for but the LaF is the same as what you want I think).

Note that if floatable is true and you move the toolbar, the LaF disappears.

---

### Code

```
toolBar = new JToolBar("TaskBar", JToolBar.VERTICAL);
toolBar.setLayout(new GridLayout(12, 1));
toolBar.setFloatable(false);
toolBar.add(buttons[0] = new JButton("Data Entry"));
toolBar.add(buttons[1] = new JButton("Operations"));
toolBar.setOrientation(JToolBar.HORIZONTAL);
```

---

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works for me.  I may want to switch to a nicely bordered JPanel set up, because I want the bar at right to have buttons on it, coming down from the top, but also with a set at the bottom running up.  I could use separators, yes?  And measure the available height and heights of things, and stick a sized separator in the toolbar between the two.

Comment: @MarkMeyers I'm afraid I do not understand the question. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Hi, with thought, I have switched to a JPanel, with buttons at the top and bottom of it, vertically on the right side of the window. I gave the panel a bevel border and its own color.